# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() rates don't come to Appstore

Tags: request, review, rate, skstorereviewcontroller

```
    if UsesCount < 10
    {
    UsesCount += 1
    }
    else
    {
        if UsesCount == 10
        {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
            UsesCount += 1
        }
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(UsesCount, forKey: "UsesCount")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

[All work right jpg attacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1EWU.jpg)

but in AppStore and AppStore Connect i don't see this rates in all versions. 
What it can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. In Appstore showed locale rates and comments. Rate which I want to found is from Russia, i can see it only in AppStore Connect by filter All rates or Russia.